# Practical example of using Castle.Windsor with MVVMLight Toolkit

Tags: mvvm-light

I have really tried but I cannot find a good working example of using the Castle IOC with MVVMLight.  Any sort of guidance in the way to dynamically generate ViewModelBase viewmodels would be appreciated.  I am trying to use Constructor Injection to associate the viewmodel with a data source, something like:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
    public MainViewModel( ISomeSortofDataRepsoitory mysomesortofdata)
    myrepo = mysomesortofdata;   /// data items in an observable collection
}
```

and I want the `ViewModelLocator` to do something like:

```
public static void CreateMain()
{
     if (_main == null)
     {
         ...
         _main = ioc.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
         ...
     }
}
```

alas, no dice. Any working examples?

Comment: OK, I go this working sort of, but it is not Blendable.  It is generating the viewmodel from the container and properly injecting the data repository as desired, but the container itself is not instantiated in design mode so no data to look at.  Must I make a dummy viewmodel just to layout the form?

Comment: Can you provide some details on what you did? I'm playing with Windsor with MvvmLight also and just don't understand this at all :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter package from NuGet. Then in your ViewModelLocator ctor

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
```

OR

Delete the ViewModelLocator class altogether, and put all your Castle Windsor configuration in

```
override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

in App.xaml.cs