# IoC - Disposing of the ViewModel after the View closes

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, viewmodel, ioc-container, dispose

How can I dispose of the ViewModel after I close my View?

I'm using SimpleIoC as an IoC container, but I think it isn't going to cut it. It's very straightforward and this is what motivated me to use it. Unfortunately as my application grew some flaws started to surface.

It *constructs* my **ViewModels** as soon as I register them. Then resolves them as soon as the Window which references them is *constructed*. Unfortunately, when I close that **Window** that same **ViewModel** stays in memory. And when I open the **Window** it uses the same **ViewModel**.

I'd like to be a little more efficient in the way my application handles memory. At the very least, I'd like to dispose of the ViewModel as soon as the Window that uses it closes. I've searched, but I've been unable to find a way to do this with *SimpleIoC*.

Another thing that I'm lost as to how I can accomplish, is to set my IoC Container to **construct** the **ViewModels** just before they're **resolved**.

And a related question: Can I make the ViewModels not be resolved when the Window that references them is, but rather when the specific View in which they're in, becomes active (the user navigates to it). This is actually not that important since my Main Window doesn't have a too large memory footprint (even though it has quite a few Views in it).

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the window and not hiding it? Are you registering your services as singletons? If so can you not register them with a more limited scope (instanced) etc. Is there no lifetime release method with SimpleIoC? - I can't see why there wouldn't be... It sounds like you might want to look at an MVVM framework like Caliburn Micro as it will take care of view/viewmodel lifecycle for you and allows composable views etc.

Comment: You might also want to look at some other IoC containers that are more full featured. I've always used Castle.Windsor since it has all the features I want (typed factories, different resolver plugins etc), not that any others are better/worse - there are quite a few lightweight but feature rich IoC containers with good performance out there

Comment: Ok after some quick Googling, it looks like SimpleIoC only supports singleton lifestyle on instances unless you register them with a key. That sounds like a pain, I'd probably use a different IoC

Comment: @Charleh Any recommendations? I need it to have the best performance possible, and I don't have much interest for any other functionality other than what I already listed. It'll also be great if it had a _View Model Locator_ of sorts, so I don't have to rewrite much of my View-ViewModel binding.

Comment: When you say you need the best performance possible, what kind of performance are we talking? Usually you won't see any sort of performance issues crop up via your container unless you are doing thousands of container resolves per second. I'd seriously consider using Caliburn Micro - it's convention based and really easy to learn, plus you can do all sorts of fancy complex stuff with a set of really simple building blocks (view/viewmodel activation lifecycle including nested viewmodels, pub/sub, convention based view/viewmodel location, decent built-in container etc)

Comment: I'm currently using _MVVM Light_. SimpleIoc practically came bundled with it. I'm looking to replace just the IoC container. At the moment I'm leaning towards Windsor. Performance-wise, I was thinking solely of memory management. I need the ViewModels to be constructed, resolved and disposed of efficiently.

Comment: That's kind of a given for any MVVM framework - Windsor is very pluggable though (I'm sure others are too) so you can likely just plug into the relevant lifecycle points to instantiate/release viewmodels etc. I've not used MVVMLight so I can't say where and when these lifecycle concerns should happen, but obviously if you are resolving from the container manually at any point you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Might also be worth adding, you don't need to explicitly release, only create as the container won't hold onto references for "transients" unless you explicitly tell it to. That means the GC should do its job assuming your viewmodel/view goes out of scope and is no longer a gc root object. The other thing you can also do is create typed factories - usually the whole dep-tree is instantiated from the composition root, but if you need things "later" on (as is common in MVVM - e.g. a popup window created from a view) you can create a typed factory - this can be used to pass args during resolution

Comment: Just looking at SimpleIoC, it looks like, assuming you just implement a wrapper for Windsor that implements `IServiceLocator` you are good to go. Another bit of Googling points here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709546/practical-example-of-using-castle-windsor-with-mvvmlight-toolkit - so it looks like there may already be a Windsor adapter which saves you a few lines of code :)